# Make sense of Notification Watcher source objective-c

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

From Notification Watcher source.

```
- (void)selectNotification:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
id sender = [aNotification object];
[selectedDistNotification release];
selectedDistNotification = nil;
[selectedWSNotification release];
selectedWSNotification = nil;
NSNotification **targetVar;
NSArray **targetList;
if (sender == distNotificationList) {
    targetVar = &selectedDistNotification;
    targetList = &distNotifications;
} else {
    targetVar = &selectedWSNotification;
    targetList = &wsNotifications;
}
if ([sender selectedRow] != -1) {
    [*targetVar autorelease];
    *targetVar = [[*targetList objectAtIndex:[sender selectedRow]] retain];
}
if (*targetVar == nil) {
    [objectText setStringValue:@""];
} else {
    id obj = [*targetVar object];
    NSMutableAttributedString *objStr = nil;
    if (obj == nil) {
        NSFont *aFont = [objectText font];
        NSDictionary *attrDict = italicAttributesForFont(aFont);
        objStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"(null)"
                                                        attributes:attrDict];
    } else {
/* Line 1 */        objStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:
                    [NSString stringWithFormat:@" (%@)", [obj className]]];
        [objStr addAttributes:italicAttributesForFont([objectText font])
                        range:NSMakeRange(1,[[obj className] length]+2)];
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
            [objStr replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,0) withString:obj];
        } else if ([obj respondsToSelector:@selector(stringValue)]) {
            [objStr replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,0)
                                  withString:[obj performSelector:@selector(stringValue)]];
        } else {
            // Remove the space since we have no value to display
            [objStr replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,1) withString:@""];
        }
    }
    [objectText setObjectValue:objStr];
/* LINE 2 */    [objStr release];
}
[userInfoList reloadData];
```

}

Over at //LINE 2 objStr is being released. Is this because we are assigning it with alloc in  //LINE 1?

Also, why is //LINE 1 not:

```
objStr = [NSMutableAttributedString* initWithString:@"(null)"
                                                    attributes:attrDict]
```

If I create a new string like

```
(NSString*) str = [NSString initWithString:@"test"];
...
str = @"another string";
```

Would I have to release str, or is this wrong and if I do that I have to use [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"test"]?
Why isn't the pointer symbol used as in [[NSString* alloc] ...?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry please ignore the last question "Why isn't the pointer symbol used as in [[NSString* alloc] ...?"

I don't know where I got that idea from...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is being released because it was allocated. The `alloc` has the effect of a `retain` and must be balanced by a `release` (or `autorelease`). Pretty much any method that begins with `init` results in an object that needs to be released. It is all about balancing the retains with the releases.

Comment: Is there a way to instantiate an object without having to release it?

Comment: No, there is no automatic garbage collection as in Java or .NET. You need to tell the runtime when you are done with the object. Using autorelease is as close as you will get but if the object is long lived you need to retain it. The above code could have used autorelease.